# PHPMyAdmin alert box - missing value in the form - all usual fields are filled out?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For some reason while using PHPMyAdmin and attempting to save a table, even though I've entered all of the information I usually do I'm getting an alert box popping up with the content "Missing value in the form!".

**Here's a screenshot of my PHPMyAdmin console (2 screens merged due to resolution):**

[*PHPMyAdmin Create Table Modal Box*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Iyi.png)

**What I've tried so far:**

- Changing the data types all to `VARCHAR` with a length of `255` (except for the `deindeal_id` column, which remained `INT` with a length of `12`).
- Encasing `description` in "`" (bacticks), thinking it may be a reserved word of some sort.
- Adding a coalition.
- Using different table engines (InnoDB, MyISAM (the one I wanted)).

I'm really stumped as to what could be causing this issue, so any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe if you define a column NOT NULL (ie. don't check the box in the Null column, you have to define a default value?

Comment: Your table name is not on the screenshot, maybe your forgot to enter it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the same error, probably a Bug.

What Lex said: "Maybe if you define a column NOT NULL (ie. don't check the box in the Null column, you have to define a default value? – Lex 20 hours ago"

- Nope. Doesn't work either and wouldn't make much sense. If you don't define a default value, the server will either insert an empty string, or fail the query; depending on settings.

Comment: Problem is solved in the latest version 3.5.5. So upgrade if possible.

Answer (score 48):

Looks like a bug. Try going to Settings -> Features -> General tab and disable Ajax.

Then, try to create a new table and it won't use the popup.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: I'm starting to dislike phpMyAdmin bit by bit now. Thank you for the tip btw. Works fine.

Comment: +1 turning off Ajax also cured the problem I was having creating a user

Comment: I can not find the Ajax setting under Settings > Features > General I'm afraid... Probably newer / older version (4.1.11)

Comment: I am not sure what version you are using, but make sure you click Features tab under Settings. At least in phpMyAdmin version 3.4.10.1 it is there. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/bdu0ht2.png

Comment: This setting has been disabled since `phpMyAdmin 4.0.0` according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19819264/865175)

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue with the SQL form (where you can paste larger blocks of MySQL code). Not sure if it's a fluke, but I selected all of my input *and then* hit Go..and it worked.

Comment: I had this same problem and don't know why the phpmyadmin of my hosted account suddenly shows this message. I've been copy-pasting code chunks for years & didn't have this problem but now. But thanks a lot for sharing this "esoteric" workaround!

Answer (score 8):

Did you give it a table name.
I had the same problem & I simply forgot to give it a table name...at the top.

Comment: Saved me some time, as that was the step I missed. I'm so used to working at the command line, I forgot the table name. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Stop & start MySQL service. You can create table.

Comment: Yeah, this did the trick. Close your browser, or close the admin, for it to reset. Then restart and the queries will work again. I think it just needs to _take rest_ after a long time of running (for those of us who rarely shut down our PCs :))

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this.... 
It turns out I was forgetting to provide a name for the new table....

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug I also "met" on phpMyAdmin v.3.5.1 - Disabling Ajax (and by default I love to disable it) will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too and I had opened same database in phpmyadmin in two separate tabs of browser . When I closed one tab and access phpmyadmin, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's a bug. what I did is to stop xampp (or if you're using wampp),
and then start them again. after that you will be able to create the table in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `USE databasename;` at the top of your query. In some versions this error seem to happen even if you did select your database, `USE databasename;` will fix this bug in those situations.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this in `4.1.11`. Seems to be a bug (again?). Disabling the popup and switching to the original theme resolved it somewhat for me, although you'll be without the popup which is a pain in the behind.

Switch back to `Original` theme:

```
Home > Theme: "Original"
```

Disable the popup:

```
Home > More settings > SQL queries > Disable: "Edit in window"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know folks. Turning off my AdBlock Plus finally solved it for me. No more **Missing value in the form!** pop-ups when trying to submit something. Whitelist phpMyAdmin domain in any style or script altering add-on you might use.