# PHP: Missing value in the form

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import these sql statements.

I get the error

> Missing value in the form!

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `login`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
  `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name',
  `user_password_hash` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
  `user_email` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT 'user''s email',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: @deepi This is a phpmyadmin error message, you won't see it if you run the statements directly in the DB.

Comment: Maybe one of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825213/phpmyadmin-alert-box-missing-value-in-the-form-all-usual-fields-are-filled-o will help you.

Comment: I tried on my localhost and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me sometimes. The workaround is very simple to me, just reload the entire page. If it doesn't work, delete cache and cookies, then restart the browser. It might be just a bug ini PHPMyAdmin.