# Disable ajax in phpmyadmin 4.0.5

Tags: ajax, phpmyadmin

I've tried to disable ajax on PhpMyAdmin config and no any effect result.
I've edited config.inc.php to include the following line:

```
$cfg['AjaxEnable'] = false;
```

But Ajax still working when access PhpMyAdmin .

My server OS : Centos 6 , and control panel : cPanel/WHM .

Installed PhpMyAdmin version : 4.0.5 .

Answer (score 1):

This configuration directive has been disabled since phpMyAdmin 4.0.0.

Comment: How can I disable "Drag to reorder"? This workaround no longer works http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/support-requests/1195/