# Change URL's in a Table through phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm not real savvy with databases at this point, but I know what I want to do.

I have a table, cgs_se_messages, that contains a column that is audio_url. In that column is a link such as, /sermons/20150118.mp3

In order for me to create a podcast feed I have to have the full URL in that field. I've already loaded over 150 of these things into my website, so how can I simply say:

In the table cgs_se_messages where the column is audio_url, replace /sermons/ with http://myurl.com/sermons/ and still keep the file name on the end? Hopefully this make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sql tab you can enter an update statement, which would look something like this:

```
UPDATE cgs_se_messages SET audio_url = replace(audio_url, '/sermons/','http://myurl.com/sermons/');
```

Comment: This worked great! My own issue was I didn't know to select the database in phpMyAdmin. Once I did that, this worked exactly how I hoped it would.

Comment: Not sure on that to be honest. The second answer to this question suggests it might be a bug in some versions of phpMyAdmin, which can be worked around by disabling ajax in your browser. But I have not seen it myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825213/phpmyadmin-alert-box-missing-value-in-the-form-all-usual-fields-are-filled-o